# c - Crash while writing a file

Tags: c, file, crash

So, while I was working on a disassembler program, I noticed that it crashes if the output filesize exceeds ~ 16 KB. The way the program works, is basically that if the input file has certain hex/binary values it will output different text to output file. It does not matter what input file has, as I've tried with many different files, and all of them give same result - crashing if output file is too big.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

if (argc < 3){
printf("Not enough arguments!\nTo be executed as: .exe inputfile outputfile");
getch();
return (0);    
}

FILE *InputFile, *OutputFile;
InputFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); // "r" = open for reading
if (InputFile == NULL){
printf("Can't open input file: %s\n", argv[1]);
getch();
return (0);
}

OutputFile = fopen(argv[2], "w+"); // "w+" = open for writing but delete old data

// data in file -> array
int i = 0;
unsigned int Instruction = 0;
unsigned int Instruction2 = 0;
unsigned int Instruction3 = 0;
unsigned int Instruction4 = 0;
int Index = 0;

int DataSize = 102400;
unsigned int temparray[DataSize/2];
unsigned int Filedata[DataSize];

for(i = 0;i < DataSize;i ++) { 
Filedata[i] = 0xFE28; //Null the array
temparray[i/2] = 0xFE28; //Null the array
} 


fread (&temparray,2,DataSize/2,InputFile); // get data to temp array
fclose(InputFile);  /* close the file */

// move from temparray to normal array
Index = 0;  
for(Index = 0;Index < DataSize/2;Index ++){ 
    if(temparray[Index] == 0xFE28){
    Index = DataSize +2;    
    } else{ 
Filedata[Index*2] = temparray[Index] & 0xFFFF;
Filedata[Index*2+1] = temparray[Index] >> 16 & 0xFFFF;

    }        
}  

Index = 0;   
// main code
for(Index = 0;Index < DataSize;){
    if(Filedata[Index] == 0xFE28){
    Index = DataSize +2;
    } else{
Instruction = Filedata[Index];
Instruction2 = Filedata[Index+1];
Instruction3 = Filedata[Index+2];
Instruction4 = Filedata[Index+3];

Instruction = _32BInsto16LIns(Instruction);
Instruction2 = _32BInsto16LIns(Instruction2);
Instruction3 = _32BInsto16LIns(Instruction3);
Instruction4 = _32BInsto16LIns(Instruction4);
Index = ReadNextInstruction(Instruction,Instruction2,Instruction3,Instruction4,OutputFile,Index);
}
}

fclose(OutputFile);  /* close the file */
return 0;
}  

int _32BInsto16LIns(Input){
int temp = (Input &0xFF00) >> 8; // leave high byte
int temp2 = (Input &0x00FF) << 8;// leave only low byte
Input = temp + temp2;           // combine rotated bytes
return(Input);
}

int ReadNextInstruction(Instruction,Instruction2,Instruction3,Instruction4,OutputFile,Index){
int temp1 = 0;
int temp2 = 0;
int temp3 = 0;
int temp4 = 0;
int temp5 = 0;
int tempI = 0;

       if (Instruction == 0x4E75){  // rts
fprintf(OutputFile,"        rts                 ; return from subroutine\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index);

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E77){  // rtr
fprintf(OutputFile,"        rtr                 ; return and restore\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index);

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E73){  //rte
fprintf(OutputFile,"        rte                 ; return from interrupt\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index);

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E71){  //nop
fprintf(OutputFile,"        nop                 ; no operation\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index);

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E77){  // rtr
fprintf(OutputFile,"        rtr                 ; return and restore\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index);

} else if (Instruction == 0x4AFC){  // illegal
fprintf(OutputFile,"        illegal                 ; cause a illegal instruction exception\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index); 

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E70){  // reset
fprintf(OutputFile,"        reset                   ; reset external devices\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index); 

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E76){  // trapv
fprintf(OutputFile,"        trapv                   ; trap on overflow\n"); 
Index ++;
return (Index);

} else if (Instruction == 0x4E72){  // stop #
fprintf(OutputFile,"        stop    #$%X                ; stop\n",Instruction2); 
Index += 2;
return (Index);
}

tempI = Instruction &0xFFF0;        // trap #
if (tempI == 0x4E40){ 
temp1 = Instruction & 0x000F;
fprintf(OutputFile,"        trap    #$%X                ; trap to interrupt #$%X\n", temp1,temp1);
Index ++;
return (Index);

} 
tempI = Instruction & 0xFFF8;       //unlk (An) 
if (tempI == 0x4E58){ 
temp1 = Instruction & 0007;
fprintf(OutputFile,"        unlk    A%X             ; unlink stack frame\n",temp1); 
Index ++;
return (Index);
}

tempI = Instruction & 0xFFF0;       //link (An),# 
if (tempI == 0x4E50){ 
temp1 = Instruction & 0007;
fprintf(OutputFile,"        link    A%X,#$%X            ; link stack frame at A%X\n",temp1,Instruction2,temp1); 
Index += 2;
return (Index);
}

tempI = Instruction & 0xFFF0;       
if (tempI == 0x4840){               // swap Dn
temp1 = Instruction & 0007;
fprintf(OutputFile,"        swap    D%X             ; swap words on D%X\n",temp1,temp1); 
Index ++;
return (Index);
}

tempI = Instruction & 0xFF00;       //jmp/jsr 
if (tempI == 0x4E00){   
// select between jmp and jsr        
temp1 = (Instruction & 0x00C0) >> 6;
if (temp1 == 3){
fprintf(OutputFile,"        jmp ");
} else if(temp1 == 2){
fprintf(OutputFile,"        jsr "); 
} else {    // if neither, is not valid jmp/jsr instruction
fprintf(OutputFile,"        dc.w    $%X\n", Instruction); 
Index ++;
return (Index);
}
// fill out the rest of the instruction    
temp3 = (Instruction & 0x0038) >> 3;
temp2 = (Instruction & 0x0007);
if (temp3 == 2){  // if jxx an
        fprintf(OutputFile,"(A%X)               \n",temp2);
        Index ++;
        return (Index);
} else if (temp3 == 7) {

    if (temp2 == 0){ // if jxx $.w
        fprintf(OutputFile,"$%X.w       \n",Instruction2);
        Index += 2;
        return (Index);
    } else if (temp2 == 1){ // if jxx $.l
        fprintf(OutputFile,"$%X%X.l     \n",Instruction2,Instruction3);
        Index += 3;
        return (Index);
    } else if (temp2 == 3) { // if jxx (Dn,pc)

        temp4 = (Instruction2 + 6) & 0x00FF;
        if (temp4 == 0){            
        fprintf(OutputFile,"(D%X,PC)    \n",(Instruction2 >> 12) & 0x7);  
        } else {
        fprintf(OutputFile,"$%X(PC,D%X) \n",temp4,(Instruction2 >> 12) & 0x7); 
        }
        Index += 2;
        return (Index);   

    } else {
    fprintf(OutputFile,"        dc.w    $%X\n", Instruction); 
    Index ++;
    return (Index);   
    }

} else {
fprintf(OutputFile,"        dc.w    $%X\n", Instruction); 
Index ++;
return (Index);
}

Index += 2;
return (Index);

}

tempI = Instruction & 0xF000;       // bxx
if (tempI == 0x6000){
fprintf(OutputFile,"        b");

temp1 = (Instruction & 0x0F00) >> 8; // figure the right extention
char* temp_extentionarr[15] = { "ra", "rs", "hi", "ls", "cc", "cs", "ne", "eq", "vc", "vs", "pl", "mi", "ge", "lt", "gt", "le" };
fprintf(OutputFile,"%s",temp_extentionarr[temp1]); // write correct extension
temp2 = (Instruction & 0x00FF) + 2; // calculate the lenght

if(temp2 == 2){ //bxx.w
fprintf(OutputFile,".w  *+$%X\n",Instruction2 + 2);
Index += 2;
return (Index);
} else { // bxx.s
fprintf(OutputFile,".s  *+$%X\n",temp2);
Index ++;
return (Index);
}

} else {
fprintf(OutputFile,"        dc.w    $%X\n", Instruction);
Index ++;
return (Index);
}


}
```

Also, I am having some trouble with fread() command, when I try to specify it to write only 2 bytes to each array position, it does 4. Am I doing something wrong?:
    fread (&temparray,2,DataSize/2,InputFile);

Comment: Also you may want to consider putting large arrays in the heap instead of allocating them on the stack.

Comment: Your array `temparray` is `unsigned int` so the size of each element of array will be `4` bytes on a 32-bit compiler. Also do you really want to read the contents of file to `&temparray`, shouldn't it be just `temparray`

Comment: I have investigated a little more, and the crash happens at loop after comment "// main code". However I am still unsure what could cause it.

Comment: I believe I have fixed this issue. It seems like it had to do with this line: **char* temp_extentionarr[15] = { "ra", "rs", "hi", "ls", "cc", "cs", "ne", "eq", "vc", "vs", "pl", "mi", "ge", "lt", "gt", "le" };** Removing the 15 there made it not crash. But thanks anyways!

Comment: That makes sense, that is in fact an array of length 16, not 15.